# Git branch from a prev commit and pull changes from master

Tags: git, merge, branch

Let's say I have made following commits.
All commits were in the same branch. In Commit 3, I deleted C and now I need to add C back to the current

```
Commit 1: A,
Commit 2: A, C 
Commit 3: A, 
.
.
.
Master (current) : A, B, D
```

And now, I want to create a branch with A, B, C, and D.
This is what I have tried.

1. create a local and remote branch at commit 2

   git checkout branch mybranch hashtag-of-commit2
2. pull changes from origin/master (current) to add B and D

   git checkout mybranch

   git fetch origin

   git merge origin/master

Doing this, it deletes C and adds B and D. The final result is A, B, D. What I'd like to have is A, B, C and D. How do I this?

Comment: Maybe it's just your notation is unconventional, but are you trying to say Commits 1, 2 and 3 all contain change A? And why should creating a branch with 4 changes involve a remote repo at all?

Comment: Note you don't 'pull changes from master'. You pull changes from a remote (e.g. `origin`). Arguably you fetch them from origin, and merge them into master. Clearing up terminology would really help us help you.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. What I wanted to do is to create a branch with changes A, B, C and D.

Comment: I appreciate that, but I'm not quite sure what you've got at the minute. Are (for instance) commits 1, 2, and 3 in the same branch? Or different branches? When you say 'change' do you mean 'changeset'? If so, how does changeset C disappear after commit 2? Try creating a diagram like the documentation on `git rebase`.

Comment: All commits were in the same branch (master). At commit 3, I deleted C. Now I need to add C back,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A whole `git revert` would also revert the changes to `A` introduced in `Commit3`, so that's not what you want.

To restore file `C` as present in `Commit2`, you have not only one option:

#### 1. Simply show the state of `C`

[`git show`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) shows the content of a file in a certain revision. So

```
git show Commit2:C > /path/to/C
```

will print the content of file `C` and will store it in `/path/to/C`. We still need to add it again to the index:

```
git add /path/to/C && git commit -m "restoring C"
```

#### 2. Partially revert the commit

We know that `C` was changed in `Commit3` in a way we don't want. To create a patch from the changes introduced in `Commit3` to `C` (i.e. it's deletion), we could use [`git diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff):

```
git diff Commit3~..Commit3 -- /original/path/to/C > c-changes.patch
```

Now, `c-changes.diff` holds the changes introduced. Now, we [apply this patch in **reverse** order](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-apply) and restore `C`:

```
git apply --reverse c-changes.patch
```

`C` is restored, re-add it to the index:

```
git add /path/to/C && git commit -m "restoring C"
```

#### 3. Rebase away the deletion

When you use the previous option, `Commit3` still removes `C` and you have an extra commit restoring `C`. If you haven't pushed anywhere since `Commit3`, we could edit `Commit3` so that it does no longer delete `C`. First, create the patch as described in option 2. Then, invoke an interactive [`git rebase`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

```
git rebase -i Commit2
```

This will bring up a dialog in your `$EDITOR`. You'll see `Commit3`. Choose to `e`dit the commit, save the file and close the file. Then, the rebasing will start and it will stop right after `Commit3` was applied. Now take your patch and apply it in reverse order:

```
git apply --reverse c-changes.patch
```

The patch was applied, now we amend the last commit and delete the deletion of `C` from history:

```
git add /path/to/C && git commit --amend -C HEAD && git rebase --continue
```

Rebasing continues after this and once it's finished, you have a fresh history where `C` was never gone.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I think the question means, in more traditional layout, changing letters for numbers and numbers for letters.

The log (single branch) looks like this

```
---A---B---C---D--- .... ---- HEAD master
       +x  -x
```

Commit B adds `x` and commit C reverts that change. OP wants to add `x` back in.

Assuming you are on master (i.e. already have the changes introduced by commits `D` .. `master`), prima facie `git revert sha-1-of-C` should do that, i.e. you are reverting the commit that reverted the original change.

I don't see what this has to do with a remote branch.